# Warning : Divison by zero on woocommerce in wc-template function

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, return-value, global, empty-list

```
function wc_get_loop_class() {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $woocommerce_loop['loop']    = ! empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) ? $woocommerce_loop['loop'] + 1   : 1;
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = ! empty( $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) ? $woocommerce_loop['columns'] : apply_filters( 'loop_shop_columns', 4 );
    if ( 0 === ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 === $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
        return 'first';
    } elseif ( 0 === $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] ) {
        return 'last';
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   /home/betawebs/public_html/tech/betawp/attwp/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php
>   on line 249 class="post-2606

My page is giving above error pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be corrected in the next stable release.
Take a look at line 260:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php